# Using defaultdict in python

Tags: python

I am reading  items from a `txt` file into a `list` and then converting it into a dictionary as follows-

```
def getfeatures_into_list(inputfilename):
    fid=open(inputfilename,"r")
    dict_Lab_Features=defaultdict(int)
    list1=[]
    for line in fid:
        list1.append(line.rstrip().lower())
    list1=list(set(list1))  #Removing duplicates
    c=0
    for items in sorted(list1):
        dict_Lab_Features[items]=c
        c+=1

    dict_Lab_Features=sorted(dict_Lab_Features.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))
    print(dict_Lab_Features['Hello'])
```

I am getting error in the print statement

```
list indices must be integer,not str
```

**Edit** I want to sort the dict by value in ascending order.

Comment: This code does nothing but assigns a number to each string based on the iteration order of a set. What would you like to achieve?

Comment: To add to @hege_hegedus's comment: It seems like you were just adding numbers so that you could put the text lines in sorted order. But you already have the lines in `list1` and you already have them in sorted order when you do `sorted(list1)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this line:

```
dict_Lab_Features=sorted(dict_Lab_Features.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))
```

you have reassigned `dict_Lab_Features` so that it is a list. This is because the output of `sorted()` is always a list. Naturally, a list cannot take a string as an index.

You should learn to think of dictionaries as *inherently* unsorted. There is such a thing as an `OrderedDict` for when you really need to keep track of insertion order, but for most purposes, a regular `dict` is fine. You just have to get into the habit of *traversing* the dictionary in the desired order, not worrying about whether the dictionary is *stored* in any kind of order.

The usual way to traverse a dictionary in sorted order is to just loop over the sorted keys, such as:

```
for key in sorted(dict_Lab_Features):
    print dict_Lab_Features[key]
```

or

```
for key, value in sorted(dict_Lab_Features.items()):
    print value
```

Or, if you want to loop over the sorted values,

```
for value in sorted(dict_Lab_Features.values()):
    print value
```

Comment: I want to loop over the sorted values not keys. Is it possible in Python?

Comment: @Noober: Sure. Use `sorted(dict_Lab_Features.values())`. Just be aware that it's a list of values. Note that if you have two keys with the same value, the value will show up twice.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot sort a dict. Dicts are unordered mappings of elements.

Let's analyize the following line:

```
dict_Lab_Features=sorted(dict_Lab_Features.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))
```

From the documentation of [sorted](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted):

> Return a new sorted list from the items in iterable.

So after that, dict_Lab_Features is a sorted list of key-value tuples. After that you try to index it with `'Hello'`

```
print(dict_Lab_Features['Hello'])
```

Here you try to index that list with `'Hello'`, that's why you get the error `list indices must be integer,not str`

Answer (score 1):

`dict_Lab_Features` stops being a `dict` when you call `dict.items()`. A `dict.items()` object cannot be addressed using string keys (it's really just a list of tuples `[(key, value), ... ]`).

Furthermore, "sorting" a dictionary you then intend to use by name doesn't make much sense either. Looks like you either need a `collections.OrderedDict` or you should skip ordering altogether